# Create desktop shortcut for Node Webkit application

Tags: exe, node-webkit, shortcut-file

I am created a `Node web-kit` application and also a `.exe` file of it using [Enigma Virtual Box](http://enigmaprotector.in/en/aboutvb.html). I uploaded the .exe in my server. On clicking a link it downloads the .exe file. What I want is that after I download the file, I want it to create a desktop shortcut automatically. Is possible to do that?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this npm https://github.com/j201/windows-shortcuts
To file current file and directory there are [__dirname](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) and [__filename](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename). Sorry, never run node on windows, but it should be something like

```
var ws = require('windows-shortcuts');
ws.create("%UserProfile%\Desktop\my_app.lnk", __filename);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried doing the same using Inno Setup. and it worked. Anyway I will also try this way. :)